# Dictionary GetValueOrDefault

Tags: c#, hash-map, extension-methods

I'm pretty sure there's no better way to do this but I thought a consensus on here might be nice. Let me know what you think.

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
{
    TValue value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Related question [Is there an IDictionary implementation that, on missing key, returns the default value instead of throwing?](//stackoverflow.com/q/538729). Better to use IDictionary

Comment: As of C# 7.1 this can be simplified to a one-liner: `public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue)) => dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : defaultValue;`

Comment: @IanKemp Removing all newlines can make anything a one-liner. It doesn't make it more maintainable.

Comment: I'd say this one-liner (or a two-liner if you break before/after the `=>` is perfectly maintainable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure there's no better way to do this but I thought a consensus on here might be nice. Let me know what you think.

At first glance it seems to be ok but one could assume that he/she is always getting **either** the value **or** the default value. If one would get the default value for e.g if the dictionary is empty, why shouldn't he/she get the default value if the dictionary is `null` or the `key` is `null` ?

If this isn't the way the method should work, then you need some documentation which cleary states the purpose and any expected exceptions.

Now, what happens if the method is called either like so

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = null;
dict.GetValueOrDefault("someKey");
```

or (assuming the method lives in the "DictionaryExtensions" class)

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = null;
DictionaryExtensions.GetValueOrDefault(dict, "someKey");
```

sure you get a `NullReferenceException` but is this the type of exception one would expect ? If I call a method with an parameter being `null` I would expect to get either no exception or to get an `ArgumentNullException`.

What about if the `key` is `null` ? Sure you get an `ArgumentNullException` but it takes some time because it is thrown at the `FindEntry()` method of the `Dictionary` and this is also shown in the `StackTrace`.

IMO it would be better to check this cases inside the `GetValueOrDefault()` method and throw the exceptions there.

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
{
    if (dictionary == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary)); } // using C# 6
    if (key == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key)); } //  using C# 6

    TValue value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: very good! but i think the *Default* word here means we like to get the default value if the item does not exist not throwing an exception... may you see [my ans](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/201182/128016) please

Comment: Good answer. I would handle null value for the `dictionary` parameter as well, throwing `ArgumentNullException`, since we explicitly use that parameter, dereferencing it before calling the `TryGetValue()` method. But, since we don't really use the `key` parameter, we shouldn't check/throw, because we don't know the internals of the TryGetValue() method, which actually uses it, and how it handles null values. Maybe its implementation will change over time and it later handle null values. From that point of view, I would avoid checking parameters we don't use but just forwaring to other methods.

Comment: I'd also change the `dictionary` parameter to be IReadOnlyDictionary instead of Dictionary, to cover a wider range of use-cases.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to handle `null` is to return the default value also in this case. It could be not acceptable in some scenarios, but I think usually it is normal expectation when you call the method **`GetValueOrDefault`**. The ***Default*** word here means you like to get the default value if the item does not exist not throwing an exception which again requires to handle it in the code and decrease the usability of this helper extension.

For example, in a web app if you want to show some values in a text input or span(label), it isn't important whether `dic` is itself null or it doesn't contain the key. So, in this case the extension can be written as following:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    /// <summary> Gets the value of specified key. Simply returns the default value if dic or key are null or specified key does not exists.</summary>
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
    {
        return (dic != null && key != null && dic.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value)) ? value : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `null` checks at all. It doesn't matter if the `key` is `null` and for the `dic` you can use the null-propagation operator: `dic?.TryGetValue` .

Comment: @t3chb0t thanks for comment. but I test and ensure that the dic null check is necessary! but the `key` null check can be probably removed. I first write the code using `dic?.TryGetValue` but the whole code will not be simpler as we get `use of Unassigned variable` error. May you test and provide full code please?

Comment: Oh, you're right... that's weird. I'll take a look...

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[Key] : defaultValue
```

so you don't need to declare `TValue`.

Comment: However, you end up doing two dictionary lookups instead of one if `dict` contains `key`, making this twice as slow as the `TryGetValue` approach.

Comment: Its O(1) constant lookup , doesn't matter how many times you do it.

Comment: No - a lookup being O(1) means that it takes the same amount of time regardless of how many items the dictionary contains. But two lookups will still take twice as much time as a single lookup. Or in other words: a method that performs _n_ O(1) operations is itself O(n).

Comment: @GorakhBorude actually, it's entirely possible to have a dictionary that is every bit as slow as a linked list for lookups, so not O(1)

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential issue when providing an argument to a method that would only be used in a certain condition. `defaultValue` is only returned when the dictionary does not contain an instance of `TValue` for the given `key`.

- What if the default value is the result of an exhaustive algorithm or a service call? It would be a pitty to fetch this object when `GetValueOrDefault` would not require it.

> ```
> public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
>    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
> {
>     TValue value;
>     return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : defaultValue;
> }
> ```

For this reason, I suggest an alteration to the method signature and a convenience overload for the initial situation. (Edited after remark below)

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
   this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, Func<TValue> defaultValueSelector)
{
    // arg checking left out for brevity
    TValue value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value 
       : defaultValueSelector != null ? defaultValueSelector() : default(TValue);
}

public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
   this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
{
     return GetValueOrDefault(dictionary, key, () => defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: This results in `dict.GetValueOrDefault(key)` being an ambiguous call, and it slows down the (more commonly used?) `TValue` variant. Also, callers that use expensive default values can easily use `TryGetValue` directly, so I don't think these trade-offs are worth it.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet (1) That's why it's never a bad idea to test code in fiddle before posting (I'll adapt it) (2) This is getting on philosophical territory. I find it hard to determine the trade-off here.

Comment: Why not let the eager variant use `TryGetValue` directly, instead of calling the lazy variant? The only 'trade-off' then would be a duplicate `TryGetValue` call, but that's hardly a problem.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet That would be the best option, avoiding unnecessary object creation and allowing for best performance.